# Press button event in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have a question how to handle event on pressing button in angular 6.  I found something like addEventListener, but I do not know how to connect this in angular with HTML code.

What I want to do is start searching in kendo-autocomplete input after in input are three chars and connect this with array from Typescript code (looping this array).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at the angular documentation, this questions is quite vague.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: For Example

<kendo-autocomplete (keyup)="onKey($event)" [data]="listValue" [placeholder]="'ENTER HERE'">       </kendo-autocomplete>

I have this kendo component. In this component is array "listValue". What I want to do is searching in this array with this input. But only if in input are minimum three chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AutoComplete's filtering functionality and add some custom logic for the min-filter length like in the following documentation example:

[DOCS AUTOCOMPLETE](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/filtering/#toc-minimum-filter-length)

I am not sure how is this related to handling button clicks in Angular in general, but typically you provide event binding and execute an event handler method when the event is triggered (as previously suggested in one of the answers):

[Angular - User Input](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#binding-to-user-input-events)